# UNION not removing duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, select, duplicates, union

I am trying to query 2 tables, return the values while combining duplicates. While `UNION` is supposed to remove duplicates, it seems to fail in this case. Note that this query is sent with PHP.

QUERY

`<?php`

`$keywords = 'MOTOR';`

`$toSend = "SELECT part as Column1, '' as Column2 FROM soldParts WHERE part LIKE '%".$keywords."%' UNION SELECT part as Column1, vin as Column2 FROM vinData WHERE part LIKE '%".$keywords."%' ORDER BY column1 ASC";`

`?>`

---

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

Column1 Column2

motor 1

motor 2

motor 2
CCDD44

motor 3
AABB1122

motor 3

---

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

Column1 Column2

motor 1

motor 2
CCDD44

motor 3
AABB1122

---

I have looked up several similar questions. However, my second column should just be merged (or concatenated), unlike other questions and/or they do not involve multiple tables. Also note that table `soldParts Column2` has no value.

Comment: motor 2
and 
motor 2 CCDD44 
are not the same row...

Comment: Are you sure a UNION is the right choice?  It's more like you're after a left outer join — `SELECT a.part, b.vin FROM soldparts AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN vinData AS b ON a.part = b.part`?  The semantics are a little dubious; a given part may be sold for multiple vehicles in general, but your data doesn't show that, and the same comment would apply to your UNION formulation too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resultset actually has no duplicates. Duplicates are rows where all columns have equal values, and no row in your resultset complies to that definition.

Presumably, you want aggregation in the outer query:

```
select column1, max(column2) column2
from (
    select part as column1, null as column2 from soldparts where part like ?
    union all
    select part as column1, vin as column2 from vindata where part like ?
)
group by column1
order by column1 asc
```

Note that I modified your query to use bind parameters (`?`); for the sake of security and efficiency, you should learn to use parameterized query rather than concatenating variables in the query string.

Answer (score 1):

To get the result you want you'll need to perform an aggregation on top of the `UNION` (but before the `ORDER BY`).

For example:

```
select Column1, max(Column2) as Column2
from (
  SELECT part as Column1, '' as Column2 
  FROM soldParts 
  WHERE part LIKE ?
  UNION 
  SELECT part, vin
  FROM vinData 
  WHERE part LIKE ?
) x
GROUP BY Column1
ORDER BY Column1
```

Comment: This would have also worked, but `GROUP BY Column1` was needed to make it run